# Recover grub from grub-rescue

Tags: grub2, bootloader, grubrescue, boot-repair

I was using Ubuntu normally and suddenly the system went haywire and I had to do a hard reset. After that I got a couple errors trying to load Ubuntu, so I switched to Windows trying to find an answer. Windows froze after about 5 minutes and now everytime I reboot I find a "grub-rescue" shell

How can I recover my system? I booted up a Ubuntu Pendrive and tried to run "boor-repair" but that didnt work. This is the log that gave me back

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6927683/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. put ubuntu live cd of the same version
2. boot with trial
3. go to gpart and identify the drive which reserved for ubuntu
4. go to terminal

commands:-

```
sudo fdisk -l
sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt (where X is a/b and Y is 5,6,or 7)
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sdX
sudo reboot
sudo update-grub(while connecting with internet)
```