# Unable to recover VM in grub boot state

Tags: grub2

So, I buggered up a VM with an unscheduled reboot and now I can't recover it.

From the grub screen ..

ls (hd0,1)/

shows a list of kernel files and images but doesn't show the root file system.

Thus I can't reboot.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your installation has `/boot` on a separate partition.  Try typing `ls (hd0,` then the `<tab>` key.  This should show you all the partitions seen by grub for `(hd0)`.  One of those should be your root, unless your root was on a different drive.

If you're just trying to access your files, then boot with the livecd iso and then mount your root from the livecd environment.  If you want to actually boot your vm again, perhaps reinstalling grub would work. These [instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420574/recover-grub-from-grub-rescue) may help you.